# IEEE Transaction issue figure over two columns

Tags: graphics, ieeetran, ieee-style

When I am trying to span a figure over two column in the template delivered by IEEE (I used the template in [this](https://template-selector.ieee.org/) website "Transactions, Journals and Letters" => "IEEE Transactions on Electron Devices" => "Original Research" => "Latex")

Some part of the paper become blue for some reason. (see picture below)

To replicate, add the following code somewhere in the paper. It actually depends on the place where the graphic is pasted, for example in "LaTeX-Specific Advice" or in the "Units" section, this bug will appear.

I am not sure how to deal with this issue. I cannot seem to be able to avoid it when I am writing my own document..

```
\begin{figure*}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.png}}
\caption{caption}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure*}
```

[image: IEEE Transactions]

This is an example of paper that has the issue using the IEEE template (I added the figure* and removed the end of the paper, without removing the end of the paper, the issue persist):

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside,web]{ieeecolor}
\usepackage{generic}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\markboth{\journalname, VOL. XX, NO. XX, XXXX 2017}
{Author \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS (February 2017)}
\begin{document}
\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS (February 2017)}
\author{First A. Author, \IEEEmembership{Fellow, IEEE}, Second B. Author, and Third C. Author, Jr., \IEEEmembership{Member, IEEE}

\thanks{This paragraph of the first footnote will contain the date on 
which you submitted your paper for review. It will also contain support 
information, including sponsor and financial support acknowledgment. For 
example, ``This work was supported in part by the U.S. Department of 
Commerce under Grant BS123456.'' }
\thanks{The next few paragraphs should contain 
the authors' current affiliations, including current address and e-mail. For 
example, F. A. Author is with the National Institute of Standards and 
Technology, Boulder, CO 80305 USA (e-mail: author@boulder.nist.gov). }
\thanks{S. B. Author, Jr., was with Rice University, Houston, TX 77005 USA. He is 
now with the Department of Physics, Colorado State University, Fort Collins, 
CO 80523 USA (e-mail: author@lamar.colostate.edu).}
\thanks{T. C. Author is with 
the Electrical Engineering Department, University of Colorado, Boulder, CO 
80309 USA, on leave from the National Research Institute for Metals, 
Tsukuba, Japan (e-mail: author@nrim.go.jp).}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
These instructions give you guidelines for preparing papers for 
IEEE Transactions and Journals. Use this document as a template if you are 
using \LaTeX. Otherwise, use this document as an 
instruction set. The electronic file of your paper will be formatted further 
at IEEE. Paper titles should be written in uppercase and lowercase letters, 
not all uppercase. Avoid writing long formulas with subscripts in the title; 
short formulas that identify the elements are fine (e.g., "Nd--Fe--B"). Do 
not write ``(Invited)'' in the title. Full names of authors are preferred in 
the author field, but are not required. Put a space between authors' 
initials. The abstract must be a concise yet comprehensive reflection of 
what is in your article. In particular, the abstract must be self-contained, 
without abbreviations, footnotes, or references. It should be a microcosm of 
the full article. The abstract must be between 150--250 words. Be sure that 
you adhere to these limits; otherwise, you will need to edit your abstract 
accordingly. The abstract must be written as one paragraph, and should not 
contain displayed mathematical equations or tabular material. The abstract 
should include three or four different keywords or phrases, as this will 
help readers to find it. It is important to avoid over-repetition of such 
phrases as this can result in a page being rejected by search engines. 
Ensure that your abstract reads well and is grammatically correct.
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Enter key words or phrases in alphabetical 
order, separated by commas. For a list of suggested keywords, send a blank 
e-mail to keywords@ieee.org or visit \underline
{http://www.ieee.org/organizations/pubs/ani\_prod/keywrd98.txt}
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{T}{his} document is a template for \LaTeX. If you are 
reading a paper or PDF version of this document, please download the 
electronic file, trans\_jour.tex, from the IEEE Web site at \underline
{http://www.ieee.org/authortools/trans\_jour.tex} so you can use it to prepare your manuscript. If 
you would prefer to use LaTeX, download IEEE's LaTeX style and sample files 
from the same Web page. You can also explore using the Overleaf editor at 
\underline
{https://www.overleaf.com/blog/278-how-to-use-overleaf-with-}\discretionary{}{}{}\underline
{ieee-collabratec-your-quick-guide-to-getting-started\#.}\discretionary{}{}{}\underline{xsVp6tpPkrKM9}

If your paper is intended for a conference, please contact your conference 
editor concerning acceptable word processor formats for your particular 
conference. 

IEEE will do the final formatting of your paper. If your paper is intended 
for a conference, please observe the conference page limits. 



\subsection{Abbreviations and Acronyms}


Define abbreviations and acronyms the first time they are used in the text, 
even after they have already been defined in the abstract. Abbreviations 
such as IEEE, SI, ac, and dc do not have to be defined. Abbreviations that 
incorporate periods should not have spaces: write ``C.N.R.S.,'' not ``C. N. 
R. S.'' Do not use abbreviations in the title unless they are unavoidable 
(for example, ``IEEE'' in the title of this article).



\subsection{Other Recommendations}
Use one space after periods and colons. Hyphenate complex modifiers: 
``zero-field-cooled magnetization.'' Avoid dangling participles, such as, 
``Using \eqref{eq}, the potential was calculated.'' [It is not clear who or what 
used \eqref{eq}.] Write instead, ``The potential was calculated by using \eqref{eq},'' or 
``Using \eqref{eq}, we calculated the potential.''

Use a zero before decimal points: ``0.25,'' not ``.25.'' Use 
``cm$^{3}$,'' not ``cc.'' Indicate sample dimensions as ``0.1 cm 
$\times $ 0.2 cm,'' not ``0.1 $\times $ 0.2 cm$^{2}$.'' The 
abbreviation for ``seconds'' is ``s,'' not ``sec.'' Use 
``Wb/m$^{2}$'' or ``webers per square meter,'' not 
``webers/m$^{2}$.'' When expressing a range of values, write ``7 to 
9'' or ``7--9,'' not ``7$\sim $9.''

A parenthetical statement at the end of a sentence is punctuated outside of 
the closing parenthesis (like this). (A parenthetical sentence is punctuated 
within the parentheses.) In American English, periods and commas are within 
quotation marks, like ``this period.'' Other punctuation is ``outside''! 
Avoid contractions; for example, write ``do not'' instead of ``don't.'' The 
serial comma is preferred: ``A, B, and C'' instead of ``A, B and C.''

If you wish, you may write in the first person singular or plural and use 
the active voice (``I observed that $\ldots$'' or ``We observed that $\ldots$'' 
instead of ``It was observed that $\ldots$''). Remember to check spelling. If 
your native language is not English, please get a native English-speaking 
colleague to carefully proofread your paper.

Try not to use too many typefaces in the same article. You're writing
scholarly papers, not ransom notes. Also please remember that MathJax
can't handle really weird typefaces.

\subsection{Equations}
Number equations consecutively with equation numbers in parentheses flush 
with the right margin, as in \eqref{eq}. To make your equations more 
compact, you may use the solidus (~/~), the exp function, or appropriate 
exponents. Use parentheses to avoid ambiguities in denominators. Punctuate 
equations when they are part of a sentence, as in
\begin{equation}E=mc^2.\label{eq}\end{equation}


Be sure that the symbols in your equation have been defined before the 
equation appears or immediately following. Italicize symbols ($T$ might refer 
to temperature, but T is the unit tesla). Refer to ``\eqref{eq},'' not ``Eq. \eqref{eq}'' 
or ``equation \eqref{eq},'' except at the beginning of a sentence: ``Equation \eqref{eq} 
is $\ldots$ .''

\subsection{\LaTeX-Specific Advice}

Please use ``soft'' (e.g., \verb|\eqref{Eq}|) cross references instead
of ``hard'' references (e.g., \verb|(1)|). That will make it possible
to combine sections, add equations, or change the order of figures or
citations without having to go through the file line by line.

Please don't use the \verb|{eqnarray}| equation environment. Use
\verb|{align}| or \verb|{IEEEeqnarray}| instead. The \verb|{eqnarray}|
environment leaves unsightly spaces around relation symbols.

Please note that the \verb|{subequations}| environment in {\LaTeX}
will increment the main equation counter even when there are no
equation numbers displayed. If you forget that, you might write an
article in which the equation numbers skip from (17) to (20), causing
the copy editors to wonder if you've discovered a new method of
counting.

{\BibTeX} does not work by magic. It doesn't get the bibliographic
data from thin air but from .bib files. If you use {\BibTeX} to produce a
bibliography you must send the .bib files. 

{\LaTeX} can't read your mind. If you assign the same label to a
subsubsection and a table, you might find that Table I has been cross
referenced as Table IV-B3. 

{\LaTeX} does not have precognitive abilities. If you put a
\verb|\label| command before the command that updates the counter it's
supposed to be using, the label will pick up the last counter to be
cross referenced instead. In particular, a \verb|\label| command
should not go before the caption of a figure or a table.

Do not use \verb|\nonumber| inside the \verb|{array}| environment. It
will not stop equation numbers inside \verb|{array}| (there won't be
any anyway) and it might stop a wanted equation number in the
surrounding equation.

If you are submitting your paper to a colorized journal, you can use
the following two lines at the start of the article to ensure its
appearance resembles the final copy:

\smallskip\noindent
\begin{small}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\verb+\+\texttt{documentclass[journal,twoside,web]\{ieeecolor\}}\\
\verb+\+\texttt{usepackage\{\textit{Journal\_Name}\}}
\end{tabular}
\end{small}



\section{Units}
Use either SI (MKS) or CGS as primary units. (SI units are strongly 
encouraged.) English units may be used as secondary units (in parentheses). 
This applies to papers in data storage. For example, write ``15 
Gb/cm$^{2}$ (100 Gb/in$^{2})$.'' An exception is when 
English units are used as identifiers in trade, such as ``3\textonehalf-in 
disk drive.'' Avoid combining SI and CGS units, such as current in amperes 
and magnetic field in oersteds. This often leads to confusion because 
equations do not balance dimensionally. If you must use mixed units, clearly 
state the units for each quantity in an equation.

The SI unit for magnetic field strength $H$ is A/m. However, if you wish to use 
units of T, either refer to magnetic flux density $B$ or magnetic field 
strength symbolized as $\mu _{0}H$. Use the center dot to separate 
compound units, e.g., ``A$\cdot $m$^{2}$.''

\begin{figure*}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.png}}
\caption{Magnetization as a function of applied field.
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption.}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure*}


\section{Some Common Mistakes}
The word ``data'' is plural, not singular. The subscript for the 
permeability of vacuum $\mu _{0}$ is zero, not a lowercase letter 
``o.'' The term for residual magnetization is ``remanence''; the adjective 
is ``remanent''; do not write ``remnance'' or ``remnant.'' Use the word 
``micrometer'' instead of ``micron.'' A graph within a graph is an 
``inset,'' not an ``insert.'' The word ``alternatively'' is preferred to the 
word ``alternately'' (unless you really mean something that alternates). Use 
the word ``whereas'' instead of ``while'' (unless you are referring to 
simultaneous events). Do not use the word ``essentially'' to mean 
``approximately'' or ``effectively.'' Do not use the word ``issue'' as a 
euphemism for ``problem.'' When compositions are not specified, separate 
chemical symbols by en-dashes; for example, ``NiMn'' indicates the 
intermetallic compound Ni$_{0.5}$Mn$_{0.5}$ whereas 
``Ni--Mn'' indicates an alloy of some composition 
Ni$_{x}$Mn$_{1-x}$.

Be aware of the different meanings of the homophones ``affect'' (usually a 
verb) and ``effect'' (usually a noun), ``complement'' and ``compliment,'' 
``discreet'' and ``discrete,'' ``principal'' (e.g., ``principal 
investigator'') and ``principle'' (e.g., ``principle of measurement''). Do 
not confuse ``imply'' and ``infer.'' 

Prefixes such as ``non,'' ``sub,'' ``micro,'' ``multi,'' and ``ultra'' are 
not independent words; they should be joined to the words they modify, 
usually without a hyphen. There is no period after the ``et'' in the Latin 
abbreviation ``\emph{et al.}'' (it is also italicized). The abbreviation ``i.e.,'' means 
``that is,'' and the abbreviation ``e.g.,'' means ``for example'' (these 
abbreviations are not italicized).
A general IEEE styleguide is available at \underline{http://www.ieee.org/authortools}.



\section{Guidelines for Graphics Preparation and Submission}
\label{sec:guidelines}



\subsection{Types of Graphics}
The following list outlines the different types of graphics published in 
IEEE journals. They are categorized based on their construction, and use of 
color/shades of gray:



\subsubsection{Color/Grayscale figures}
{Figures that are meant to appear in color, or shades of black/gray. Such 
figures may include photographs, illustrations, multicolor graphs, and 
flowcharts.}

\subsubsection{Line Art figures}
{Figures that are composed of only black lines and shapes. These figures 
should have no shades or half-tones of gray, only black and white.}

\subsubsection{Author photos}
{Head and shoulders shots of authors that appear at the end of our papers. }

\subsubsection{Tables}
{Data charts which are typically black and white, but sometimes include 
color.}


\subsection{Multipart figures}
Figures compiled of more than one sub-figure presented side-by-side, or 
stacked. If a multipart figure is made up of multiple figure
types (one part is lineart, and another is grayscale or color) the figure 
should meet the stricter guidelines.


\subsection{File Formats For Graphics}\label{formats}
Format and save your graphics using a suitable graphics processing program 
that will allow you to create the images as PostScript (PS), Encapsulated 
PostScript (.EPS), Tagged Image File Format (.TIFF), Portable Document 
Format (.PDF), Portable Network Graphics (.PNG), or Metapost (.MPS), sizes them, and adjusts 
the resolution settings. When 
submitting your final paper, your graphics should all be submitted 
individually in one of these formats along with the manuscript.

\subsection{Sizing of Graphics}
Most charts, graphs, and tables are one column wide (3.5 inches/88 
millimeters/21 picas) or page wide (7.16 inches/181 millimeters/43 
picas). The maximum depth a graphic can be is 8.5 inches (216 millimeters/54
picas). When choosing the depth of a graphic, please allow space for a 
caption. Figures can be sized between column and page widths if the author 
chooses, however it is recommended that figures are not sized less than 
column width unless when necessary. 

There is currently one publication with column measurements that do not 
coincide with those listed above. Proceedings of the IEEE has a column 
measurement of 3.25 inches (82.5 millimeters/19.5 picas). 

The final printed size of author photographs is exactly
1 inch wide by 1.25 inches tall (25.4 millimeters$\,\times\,$31.75 millimeters/6 
picas$\,\times\,$7.5 picas). Author photos printed in editorials measure 1.59 inches 
wide by 2 inches tall (40 millimeters$\,\times\,$50 millimeters/9.5 picas$\,\times\,$12 
picas).

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome  t TeX SX! Did you notice the header in your image mentions `generic colorized journal`?

Comment: thanks:)
 I didn't notice before, does it has an influence on the issue ? (Some title are supposed to be colored, but in my case whole paragraphs start to be blue, which is quite weird)

Comment: I don't know – it's only a conjecture , but I suppose ‘colorized’ is not there by accident. I couldn't check the template code on the site you link to, because I didn't see any page linking to IEEE Transactions on Electronic Devices.

Comment: oh I am going to fix the link ( https://template-selector.ieee.org/ ) Currently it is working, but it is very random.. Which makes it quite frustrating :(

Comment: Compiling the template, I have no problem as you have. The section, subsection, figure labels and the like are in blue (this is designed by the ieeecolor class), so you must have something else. Can you post a minimal, yet complete, example code illustrating your problem?

Comment: I added a complete & minimal example that has this issue in the post. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: For me, the problem is solved simply loading the `caption` package.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a package-related issue. Use the package `caption`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Tex.SE. Your answer is technically correct (which is the best kind of correct), but note that this exact answer was already givven in the comments above by @Bernard. For future question/answers please read also the prevoius comments below them.

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}{#1.\color{black}\normalcolor}{#1.\normalcolor}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}{#1.\color{black}\normalcolor}{#1.\normalcolor}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you explain (with an edit to your answer) what this code does, what the original problem was and how this code addresses that problem?